# PHP Showing only first result of array after sorting with asort?

Tags: php, arrays, asort

I have an array containing only numbers, i want to sort them using **asort** so it shows the lowest number first.

but now i have the array sorted, how do i make it show only the first result?

For instance, this is my array:

```
Array ( [0] => 399 [1] => 349  )
```

and after asort:

```
Array ( [1] => 349 [0] => 399 )
```

how do i echo only the first result after i asort as i cant just use Array[1] because it might not always be [1] etc..

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but its late and my brain has ceased to function correctly lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`sort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) which won't maintain key association.

```
$array = array(399, 349);
sort($array);
print_r($array);
// Array ( [0] => 349 [1] => 399 )
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Dn1tbe)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this: `echo current($array);` or `$first=current($array);`

No need to `reset()` because the array is automatically reset after being sorted.